# Text Not Vertically Aligned in li

Tags: css

I'm working on a menu and having some trouble with text not appearing the way I'd like it to. 
[image]

Here is a screenshot of what I'm having trouble with. There appears to be extra space below the link—the top and bottom aren't equal. There is no padding there, either. It is just a link within an `<li>`. What do I have wrong?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 184px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
a:link, a:active {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
  line-height: 2em;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #adadad;
}
a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't forget to include your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no issues.  Apply your css styles to your A tag though, not the li.  Also, for clarity to see what is going on, I put a border around each a tag.  Check out the fiddle, everything looks fine to me.  Height in DIV's is automatic if you don't set it statically.  i.e., it all looks fine, I see no extra spacing with the CSS I provided below.

http://jsfiddle.net/4dbuuuq4/

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 184px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
li a:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#fff;

}
a:link,
a:active {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
}
a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `line-height: 2em;` you can better see that there's more space below the text than above: https://jsfiddle.net/4dbuuuq4/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell` instead of `inline-block` and use `height` instead of `line-height` on `a`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 184px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
a:link,
a:active {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #adadad;
}
ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```